# How to save full webpage as a pdf with images, etc, in a muti page format?

Tags: pdf, conversion, html

So, I am trying to take my e-portfolio and make a pdf version because my uni is playing hot potatoe with the website keeping my portfolio.

I wanted links preserved as well as documents, but in the end, I figure I can do that with a pdf editor later. What I need without compromise is to make the pdf look professional-that is mutiple pages if the web page is long. H

Is there a program to do this? I tried sejda html to pdf and it works perfectly minus the fact it does a single page pdf.

Please help.

Comment: https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/fireshot/

Comment: Firefox also has a built-in HTML-to-PDF "printer" with options to set paper size, include headers or not, simplify page (exclude side bars), etc. that will make the portfolio look more professional.

Comment: It doesn't work well with my pdf the print pdf.

Comment: I suggest you elaborate your question to include the full scope of what you've tried so far (as it would save people making suggestions you've already tried), and also to include a copy of the PDF output you are ending up with, and clarification on what you need improved in it. Otherwise your question is simply too vague to provide a meaningful answer.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to achieve what you want using a browser add—on / extension. In my experience, Firefox and Chrome (and any Chromium based browser) have the best extension options.

I personally only use a browser extension for this when I specifically want the entire web page as **one** PNG or PDF page. Since you want long web pages split into multiple pages in the PDF file, you can likely just use the Print feature in Chrome. As shown here:

[image]

If that doesn't meet your needs, then perhaps these two extensions will. A possible advantage to a browser extension (paid version) is that it may allow you to accomodate the page breaks in a better way (as mentioned below).

### USING BROWSER EXTENSIONS

#### CHROME

The extension I used for what wish to do is called [GoFullPage](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gofullpage-full-page-scre/fdpohaocaechififmbbbbbknoalclacl). It works really well. I've only ever needed the free version. Although if you want to fine tune the page breaks on pages that take up more than one PDF page, you may need to use the Premium version of GoFullPage.

#### FIREFOX

On Firefox the add-on I use is [FireShot](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/fireshot/). It also works well, and it also has a premium version if you need the extended features it provides for a fee.

#### ONE FINAL PDF?

If you are wanting to capture all pages in your site, into one PDF, you can combine all the PDFs produced by the browser extension — after you've created them. I don't know of a tool / app that will do that in one go for you (i.e., capture every page on a site, and produce one PDF with all pages in it). It's a minor task to combine PDF files into one PDF though. The easiest way to go about it will depend on what OS you're using (Windows, macOS, Linux, etc.).

### USING ACROBAT PRO

If you own or have access to Adobe Acrobat DC Pro (not free version) as a stand-alone app or via an Adobe Cloud subscription, that has a tool for converting an entire website into a single PDF file. You can learn more about that [here](https://helpx.adobe.com/nz/acrobat/using/converting-web-pages-pdf.html).

[image: acrobat convert site to pdf]

Comment: I wish these worked. I've tried different extensions as well as the print to pdf and the pdf looks horrible-nothing like what I was trying to print. Someone said something about taking the 1 page pdf and use a pdf editor and "split" pages. So I will look into this as well as that Firefox one.

Comment: I spent over a month trying to get Adobe pro to work. Sigh. Thanks for trying.

Comment: So both FireShot and GoFullPage are not creating a satisfactory PDF file? I suggest you elaborate your question to include what you've tried so far (as it would save people like me making suggestions you've already tried), and also to include a copy of the PDF output you are ending up with, and clarification on what you need improved in it.